# Why am i not able to insert multiple values at a time by this code?

Tags: oracle

I have created the table successfully but not able to insert multiple values by this code. What is the mistake. Oracle Code

```
CREATE TABLE sales (
    customer_id VARCHAR2(4)
    ,order_date DATE
    ,product_id VARCHAR2(5)
    );

INSERT INTO sales
VALUES (
    'A'
    ,'01-JAN-2021'
    ,'2'
    );(
    'A'
    ,'07-JAN-2021'
    ,'2'
    );(
    'A'
    ,'10-JAN-2021'
    ,'3'
    );(
    'A'
    ,'11-JAN-2021'
    ,'3'
    );(
    'A'
    ,'11-JAN-2021'
    ,'3'
    );(
    'B'
    ,'01-JAN-2021'
    ,'2'
    );(
    'B'
    ,'02-JAN-2021'
    ,'2'
    );(
    'B'
    ,'04-JAN-2021'
    ,'1'
    );(
    'B'
    ,'11-JAN-2021'
    ,'1'
    );(
    'B'
    ,'16-JAN-2021'
    ,'3'
    );(
    'B'
    ,'01-FEB-2021'
    ,'3'
    );(
    'C'
    ,'01-JAN-2021'
    ,'3'
    );(
    'C'
    ,'01-JAN-2021'
    ,'3'
    );(
    'C'
    ,'07-JAN-2021'
    ,'3'
    );
```

Comment: It looks like multi-tuple `VALUES` syntax is not even supported, but even if it were, your tuples should be separated by comma, not semicolon.

Answer (score 4):

Why? because that's invalid syntax in Oracle.

One option is this:

```
SQL> INSERT INTO sales VALUES ('A', DATE '2021-01-01', '2');

1 row created.

SQL> INSERT INTO sales VALUES ('A', DATE '2021-01-07', '2');

1 row created.

SQL> INSERT INTO sales VALUES ('A', DATE '2021-01-10', '3');

1 row created.

etc.
```

Note that you shouldn't insert strings into `date` datatype column; I used date literal; you could use `TO_DATE` with appropriate format model.

---

Another option is e.g.

```
SQL> INSERT ALL
  2    INTO sales VALUES ('A', DATE '2021-01-01', '2')
  3    INTO sales VALUES ('A', DATE '2021-01-07', '2')
  4  SELECT * FROM DUAL;

2 rows created.
```

or

```
SQL> INSERT INTO sales
  2     SELECT 'A', DATE '2021-01-01', '2' FROM DUAL
  3     UNION ALL
  4     SELECT 'A', DATE '2021-01-07', '2' FROM DUAL;

2 rows created.
```

Comment: It should be noted that multiple values are standard SQL since 1992, but Oracle still doesn't support the full `VALUES` syntax. More about this here: https://modern-sql.com/feature/values. This feature has of course been requested for a long time, but I cannot even find the original old request in the database feaure requests section that Oracle hides so well in their gruesome [Database Ideas forum](https://community.oracle.com/tech/apps-infra/categories/database-ideas-ideas).